# Using HTTP API stage variable from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

In AWS API Gateway / HTTP API (not REST API), I've set a stage variable. Is there a way to get the value of that variable in a Lambda function that's called through that API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format), you can get `stage` via `requestContext -> stage`.

Comment: Shoudn't it be `stageVariables`?